# How to initialize an ObservableCollection<T>

Tags: c#, wpf, generics, observablecollection

I'm looking to generalize the logic of initializing an ObservableCollection. For example:

```
'private ObservableCollection<T> _dataList;
public ObservableCollection<T> DataList
{
    get { return _dataList; }
    set { SetField(ref _dataList, value, () => DataList); }
}'
```

and I want to initialize it like
' DataList = new ObservableCollection();'
How to do it?

I know I can also use dynamic instead of , but, I am avoiding that way

Comment: What is the problem with your `_dataList = new ObservableCollection<T>();` approach?

Answer (score 3):

An ObservableCollection property should usually be read-only:

```
public ObservableCollection<T> DataList { get; } = new ObservableCollection<T>();
```

You would later only add or remove elements - or possibly clear - the once initialized collection.

Comment: Making an obsevablecollection read only isn't a given.  IME. It's often useful to be able to tolist data and replace the entire observablecollection. Observablecollection can take a list in a ctor. Making it read only only suits adding one item at a time.

Comment: @Andy Pretty sure that in most cases that's *not* necessary. That's why there is "usually" in my post. There may *of course* be exceptions. And in case the application would make multiple assignments, the property would most certainly not need to be initialized to a non-null value at all.